# Table is not created in DB using springboot

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to create a Registration Table using springboot `Entity` class

```
//this is entity class

    @Entity
    @Table(name="RegsitrationPage")
    public class Register {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="reg_id")
    private long regId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name="account_Type")
    private AccountType acountype;

    @Column(name="first_Name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_Name")
    private String lastName;

    @NumberFormat
    @Column(name="mobile_Number")
    private long mobileNumber;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="date_Of_Birth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="Gender")
    private Gender gender;

    @Email
    @Column(name="email",unique=true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="confirm_Password")
    private String confirmPassword;

    @Column(name="address_Line")
    private String addressLine;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name="country")
    private String Country;

    @Column(name="Pincode")
    private int pincode;

    @Column(name="photo_Id_proof")
    private String PhotoIdProof;

    @Column(name="photo_Id_Card-Number")
    private String photoIdCardNumber;

    @Column(name="institution_Type")
    private String institutionType;

    @Column(name="institution_Name")
    private String institutionName;

    @Column(name="upload_photo")
    private String uploadPhoto;

      //constructor and getters and setters are created here
     }
```

I have updated my maven and run the application I got error in console like this

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-number varchar(255), pincode integer, state varchar(255), upload_photo varchar(' at line 1

along with this error

```
  Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path 
  resource 
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.c
 lass]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [create table regsitration (reg_id bigint not null auto_increment, photo_id_proof varchar(255), account_type integer, address_line varchar(255), city varchar(255), confirm_password varchar(255), country varchar(255), date_of_birth date, email varchar(255), first_name varchar(255), gender varchar(255), institution_name varchar(255), institution_type varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), mobile_number bigint, password varchar(255), photo_id_card-number varchar(255), pincode integer, state varchar(255), upload_photo varchar(255), primary key (reg_id)) ENGINE=InnoDB]
```

Comment: anybody help me

Comment: error got cleared..in column photo_Id_Card-Number....i was used hyphen instead of underscore....